# Is there a replacement for numpy-stubs in the numpy codebase?

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

I'm trying to run [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) on a codebase in which I use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) and get the following error when I `import numpy` and run mypy:

```
Skipping analyzing 'numpy'
```

Now, I can just ignore numpy as an import throughout the codebase, but I see that there is a [now-archived repository](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs) for setting up numpy-stubs that play nice with mypy. This archived repostory's readme claims that:

> These stubs have been merged into NumPy, and all further development will happen in the NumPy main repo. We welcome your contributions there!

However, if you go to numpy's Github and search "mypy", there's no clear documentation/stub support in the repo. Does anyone know what happened here? Has numpy main not actually integrated these stubs yet?

Comment: it should happen in the next release

Comment: https://github.com/predictive-analytics-lab/data-science-types has type stubs

Comment: Meanwhile, `pip install git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs` until the next release of `numpy` arrives.

Comment: Which release of numpy will include the stubs? 1.20?

Comment: Looks like Numpy v1.20.0 will include the typing stubs. The (pre-release) release notes are already available: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#numpy-is-now-typed